# google-translate-api in an Angular 2

Tags: angular, api, translate

I would like to play with the (free) google-translate-api in an Angular 4 app and it's not at all obvious to me how to import, inject and use this. I am fairly new to Angular so I'm sure that is part of the problem. I have seen the docs at https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-translate-api, but I don't know how to use it in Angular 4.what I do install google-transalte-api

In my AppComponent.ts

```
constructor(private translate: Translate,private _http: Http ){
translate('Ik spreek Engels', {to: 'en'}).then(res => {       
console.log(res);
//=> I speak English
console.log(res.from.language);
//=> nl
})
}
```

**Errors:**

```
ERROR in ./~/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'D:\jboss-eap-
6.2\standalone\deployments\geniush5.ear\copl.war\node_modules\graceful-fs'
@ ./~/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js 1:9-22
@ ./~/configstore/index.js
@ ./~/google-translate-token/index.js
@ ./~/google-translate-api/index.js
@ ./app/component/customer/controller/CustomerController.ts
@ ./app/app.ts

ERROR in ./~/mkdirp/index.js 
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'D:\jboss-eap-
6.2\standalone\deployments\geniush5.ear\copl.war\node_modules\mkdirp'
@ ./~/mkdirp/index.js 2:9-22
@ ./~/configstore/index.js
@ ./~/google-translate-token/index.js
@ ./~/google-translate-api/index.js
@ ./app/component/customer/controller/CustomerController.ts
@ ./app/app.ts

ERROR in ./~/osenv/osenv.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in 'D:\jboss-eap-
6.2\standalone\deployments\geniush5.ear\copl.war\node_modules\osenv'
@ ./~/osenv/osenv.js 3:11-35
@ ./~/configstore/index.js
@ ./~/google-translate-token/index.js
@ ./~/google-translate-api/index.js
@ ./app/component/customer/controller/CustomerController.ts
@ ./app/app.ts
```

help should be appreciated.

Comment: I have used it successfully with plain express, but I cannot get it to work with react with the same error. It's not even with the code but the import for me. try commenting all code related to the translate except for import and does it break? It breaks for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
const { response } = require('express')
const express = require('express')
const translate = require('google-translate-api');
  
app.get('/api/translate/:myInputText', (req, res) => {
    translate(req.params.myInputText , {to: 'ar'}).then(trans => {
    res.send(`Translate :${trans.text} , inputText : ${req.params.myInputText}`)
    }).catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
    });
})


const port = process.env.PORT || 3000
app.listen(port , ()=> console.log(`Listening at  port : ${port}`))
```

`USE OF Google Translate API ( STEPS FOR NODE EXPRESS )`
`1-install nodejs LTS` (https://nodejs.org/en/download/)
`2-open a directory of your project`
`3-npm init --yes`     ( to create package json file)
`4-npm i google-translate-api`
`5-create index.js file in your project folder`
`6-just copy paste the above code snippet`
`7-node index.js` in cli
`8-http://localhost:3000/api/translate/EnterTextToTranslate` Test It